# Escape HTML attributes that contain < and >

Tags: php, mysql

I am saving HTML to a MySQL database. The HTML is posted back from the front-end. I get an issue where certain characters are 'unescaped' by the front-end (rightly so) but I need to 'escape' them again prior to saving the HTML to the database.

As an example; the browser gets sent the following:

```
<p style-id=".btn-widget &gt; a">foo</p>
```

The browser then sends back something like:

```
<p style-id=".btn-widget > a">clients custom text</p>
```

Note the `&gt;` is now a `>`. I need to escape this before saving this HTML to the MySQL database.

Is there a PHP function that can do this for me?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: you can use `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Use htmlspecialchars() to remove. If there is already inserted data strip_tags() to get clean output

Comment: what you get after using strip_tags() function. It should remove P tag completely.

Comment: I think you might hit a couple of problems here - firstly you're going to need to be able to parse the value of the `style-id` attribute separately from the rest of the HTML; using something like `htmlspecialchars()` will convert all the HTML tags you want to keep as well, e.g. `&lt;p style-id=".btn-widget &gt; a"&gt;foo&lt;/p&gt;`. To get the `style-id` attribute values you'll probably want to use a DOM parser, but AFAIK `style-id` isn't a valid HTML attribute to start with so you'll need to use a generic XML parser... I just have a feeling you're going about this the wrong way.